# Installing PHP GD Library Ubuntu Mystery

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have been trying to enable GD for php but had no luck so far. I did manage to install GD - just isn't enabled for some reason.

[image]

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and php5 and php5.6 are both enabled. This is because I never did a2dismod php5 after installing php5.6 from a the ondrej repository. My guess it probably uses the gd.ini when doing a2dismod php5 - But when I a2dismod php5 I receive virtual server errors so I rather leave it enabled instead of troubleshooting that... I have a live-site with a thousand visitors a day so I don't want to mess around with it too much.
PHP runs over FCGid

[image]

Any thoughts how to enable GD from here?

Yes, I restarted apache2 service :)

Thank you!

Regards
Rob